# What is '%1' in a PyQt ImportError?

Tags: python, pyqt4

When I tried `from PyQt4 import QtGui` in IDLE 3.5.2 - 32 bit, I got this ImportError:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I found out that the PyQt4 I had was 64-bit, and installing the right Python fixed the problem, but I'm still wondering what `%1` is. Is it a file, or some exclusive PyQt label? I guessed it must've been some `%1.dll` from the ImportError, so I tried `dir \%1.dll /s` in cmd, but it didn't return any files. I googled "%1 pyqt", but the results were more about fixing the error instead of saying what it is.

Comment: It's just a placeholder that would normally get replaced by the name of the dll. I don't know exactly *why* it doesn't get replaced, though. It's probably part of an error message coming from Windows.

Comment: @ekhumoro Oh ok. "placeholder" is probably the best answer then. I googled `%1 error`. There's even an [error](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00318556) in some hp printers, and that's probably a placeholder too. I can accept your comment as an answer then. Thanks.